# Count Null Instances in Python RDD

Tags: python, lambda, null, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Python RDD of strings. I want to figure how many of these values are null. Here is an idea of how the file has been read in:

```
matrix = sc.textFile("txtFile.txt").map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
```

So, what I have is an RDD of strings that have been split on the tabs. `matrix.first()` returns:

`[u'1,2010-07-06', u'198125.0', u'0.24641', u'0.27543', u'0.27603', u'8123537.0', u'263157.0', u'3.0', u'13223919.95', u'0.341464030112', u'248514.0', u'3.0', u'30.438234', u'0.3004', u'412455.0', u'22.0', u'-14643.0', u'', u'', u'1']`

My final goal is to figure out how many missing values there are by column. I'm having trouble converting from strings to floats. Here is what I tried first:

`vals = matrix.map(lambda x: [float(x)])`

However, I get an error `float() argument must be a string or a number`

I tried this:

`test = matrix.first() 
float(test[33]) # since the item at 33 is null`

This yields the same error as before. So, maybe I need to get rid of the missing values.

`vals = matrix.map(lambda x: [float(x if len(x) > 0 else '-99.99')])`

This was an attempt to get rid of the missing values with an easily identifiable but likely nonexist number in my dataset, then I could count this -99.99 after. However, I come across the same error.

Is there a better way to do this? I just want to get a summary of how many nulls there are in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import numpy as np
matrix.map(lambda xs: np.array([0 if x else 1 for x in xs])).sum()
```

Regarding your attempts:

```
vals = matrix.map(lambda x: [float(x)])
```

doesn't fail because of the empty strings (it would but it doesn't reach this part) but because element passed as `x` argument is a `list`.

Comment: Sorry, just a little confused. What does you code do in matrix.map(lambda xs...)? I can see you are summing, but how are you singling out the null values? It seems like you are assigning everything to either 1 or 0 although I'm not understanding your criteria.

Comment: Empty sequence in Python evaluates to False. You can see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) for more but it means you can use `if some_sequence: do_something` instead of checking `len`. Inside a comprehension I generate binary vector with 1 when string is empty. It is wrapped with `np.array` so we can use `RDD.sum` to get column-wise totals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are applying the lambdas per line.

The error message refers to the fact that you are calling float(x) *on each line of matrix*, so x is a list of Strings.

You would have to do:

```
matrix = sc.textFile("clean-sl-mix-with-labels.txt").map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))

def clean_row(row):
    return ['-99.99' if len(element) == 0 else float(element)  for element in row]

matrix.map(clean_row)
```

On top of that, you have a first column (u'1,2010-07-06') that will give you an exception when trying to transform it to float, because it doesn't have an appropriate format.